# Is there a way I can check to see if the file is already open?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, file, streamwriter

I want to check if C:\Data.xlsb is already open or not.

I have got following code from here [How to tell if a certain Excel file is open using VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915926/how-to-tell-if-a-certain-excel-file-is-open-using-vb-net)

```
Public Shared Function OpenUnlockedFile(ByVal path As String) As StreamWriter
Dim sw As StreamWriter = nothing
Try
    sw = New StreamWriter(path)
Catch ex As IOException When System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() = 32
    REM locked, return nothing
End Try
Return sw
End Function
```

But I dont know how to use the code above.

I prefer sub instead of function.

Best regards.

Comment: Why do you prefer a Sub over a Function?? A function is way better if you want to check if the file is opened or not, as you can make it return True or False, thus you can check it in an `If`-statement.

Comment: I'd suggest you modified the return type to a `Boolean`, and return `True` in the last line of your function, and return `False` in the `Catch` block. I also think that a `FileStream` would be better than a `StreamWriter`.

Comment: @VisualVincent Could you please post the code you adviced?

Comment: Sure, give me a few sec...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use this code, you would use the function as in the following example:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If OpenUnlockedFile("C:\Data.xlsb") Is Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("File is locked")
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function OpenUnlockedFile(ByVal path As String) As StreamWriter
        Dim sw As StreamWriter = Nothing
        Try
            sw = New StreamWriter(path)
        Catch ex As IOException When System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() = 32
        REM locked, return nothing
        End Try
        Return sw
    End Function

End Class
```

The function, OpenUnlockedFile("C:\Data.xlsb") is run whenever you press Button1 (in this example).  If the function is run and it returns Nothing, then you will know the file is locked.

Please note that you will also need

```
Imports System.IO
```

for this example to work.

Comment: That does not tell him if it is opened or not, practically it does nothing unless you check it in like an `If`-statement.

Comment: I saw that as well and made the edit a few minutes ago!

Answer (score 2):

You should change the return type to `Boolean` to better fit your needs, and also switch from a `StreamWriter` to a `FileStream`. This is because in the post you linked the OP wanted to write to the file, which I don't think you want (or at least not using a plain text `StreamWriter`).

```
Public Shared Function IsFileAvailable(ByVal path As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim fs As New FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
        fs.Close()
    Catch ex As IOException When System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() = 32
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True
End Function
```

Then you would just use it like this:

```
If IsFileAvailable("C:\Data.xlsb") = True Then
    'File is not locked, do what you like here.
Else
    MessageBox.Show("The file is locked!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If
```

Please note that either function will only tell you if the file is accessible, it's possible that a process has opened it without locking it.